# CPU support for virtualization

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, history

When did the AMD and Intel CPUs start to have features to support virtualization to allow multiple OSes to run at the same time on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel: November 13, 2005

AMD: May 23, 2006

Check the Wikipedia article on [X86 virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization).